# Failed to acquire lock for git repository in JAVA Spring MVC code in Eclipse

Tags: git, maven, spring-mvc

```
The project was not built due to "Failed to acquire lock for git repository.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent   mobeeload       Unknown Java Problem
```

I go the above the error when tried to built along with the following error also.

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for com.juasoft.mobeeload.dao.AccountsDAOImpl  servlet-context.xml /mobeeload/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet    line 68 Spring AOP Problem
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for com.juasoft.mobeeload.dao.UsersDAOImpl servlet-context.xml /mobeeload/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet    line 50 Spring AOP Problem
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for com.juasoft.mobeeload.dao.InventoryDAOImpl servlet-context.xml /mobeeload/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet    line 59 Spring AOP Problem
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for com.juasoft.mobeeload.dao.ManageDAOImpl    servlet-context.xml /mobeeload/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet    line 77 Spring AOP Problem
```

Tried **Maven Update** as well as **project clean** and **built** several times and failed to clear the issue.

**UPDATE**

Some issue with **xml** file my **target** folder is shown in **servlet-context.xml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got same error once, Solved by

- Turn off **'Projects -> Build Automatically'**
- Removed **target** folder by terminal
- **Projects -> Clean**
- Compile project